# variable need initialization in for loop, but not do while loop?

Tags: java

I just want to calculate your future age. You enter 3 things: your current age, the current year, and the future year. I was experiementing with `for` and `do while` loops. Then I came cross this problem, variable `currentAge` is not initialized. But none of the other variables are initialized either, other variables are fine. The only difference here is others are in the `do while` loop, but `currentAge` is in the `for` loop. Why did this happen? Can somebody explain the difference and why? Please see the below code.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Lab3Class 
{ 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String cleanUpStr; 
        int currentAge; 
        int futureAge; 
        int currentYear; 
        int futureYear;

        for (int cntr = 0; cntr < 3; ++cntr) 
        { 

            System.out.print("Enter your current age\t"); 

            currentAge = input.nextInt( ); 

            cleanUpStr = input.nextLine( ); 
        }

    if (currentAge >= 0){

        do 
        { 
            System.out.print("Enter current year\t"); 

            currentYear = input.nextInt( ); 

            cleanUpStr = input.nextLine( ); 
        } while(currentYear < 0); 

        do 
        { 
            System.out.print("Enter future year\t"); 

            futureYear = input.nextInt( ); 
            cleanUpStr = input.nextLine( ); 
        } while(futureYear < 0 || futureYear < currentYear);

        input.close();
        futureAge = currentAge + (futureYear - currentYear);

        System.out.println("In the year " + currentYear + " you are " + currentAge + " years old"); 
        System.out.println("In the year " + futureYear + " you will be " + futureAge + " years old"); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Too many tries for an valid age!");
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The **do / while** loop code block is executed once (at least) **no matter what the condition is**. But the for loop **does not follow** the same tradition : The for loop checks whether the condition is valid **FIRST**, **THEN it executes**.

Execution DEMO:

### For loop : `(pre; condition; post)`

1. Check the condition -> If condition is **true** -> 2. Execute code block -> 3. Go on to next iteration

### Do / While loop:    `do { }while(condition);`

1. Execute code block -> 2. Check condition -> If condition is **true** -> 3. Go on to next iteration.

Comment: And consequently it could happen that "currentAge" has not been initialized when it is read in the if-statement.

Comment: That exaplaied my question. Thanks man!! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this version of code it's perfect:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3Class {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cleanUpStr;
    int currentAge = 0;
    int futureAge;
    int currentYear;
    int futureYear;

    System.out.print("Enter current age\t");
    currentAge = input.nextInt();

    if (currentAge >= 0) {
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter current year\t");
            currentYear = input.nextInt();
            cleanUpStr = input.nextLine();
        } while (currentYear < 0);

        do {

            System.out.print("Enter future year\t");
            futureYear = input.nextInt();

            cleanUpStr = input.nextLine();
        } while (futureYear < 0 || futureYear < currentYear);

        input.close();
        futureAge = currentAge + (futureYear - currentYear);

        System.out.println("In the year " + currentYear + " you are "
                + currentAge + " years old");
        System.out.println("In the year " + futureYear + " you will be "
                + futureAge + " years old");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Too many tries for an valid age!");
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it works - you just need to change currentAge declaration line setting it to initial value, like this:

```
int currentAge = 0;
```

Java initialize class fields with default values, but not methods variables. 
As an alternative solution (just to improve understanding) I would recommend to move declaration of currentAge to class level and leave it without default value, like following:

```
public class Lab3Class
{

    private static         int currentAge;
...
}
```

The program behavior will be the same, but will depict difference between field and method variable declaration and initialization.

You may find useful following links: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5